# MQL5 - Pass Indicator as parameter

Tags: mql5, forex, metatrader5

I was wondering if there is a way to pass an Indicator Definition or the Indicator as a parameter to a constructor of a class.
The point is to create a class, that accept the indicator and use it to generate specific values, or even initialized indicator definition to get values

Comment: What would be the use to pass a random indicator to a class? Since all indicators have different values wouldn't it make more sense to pass a `signal` into a class? e.g. `MyDecider decider(signal);`

Comment: Update, sorry to not specify, i mean MQL5

Comment: nicholishen, that's something i didn't thought off xD
but to think, i have a class for each indicator, the input parameters change, and the buffer number change, i was going to make a loop that take argument from the constructor of how may buffers, didn't thought about the varied parameters

Comment: varied number of parameters and varied buffer numbers are evil, why didn't they make an array of values to be passed, or something like MqlTradeRequest and MqlTradeResult for the indicators

Answer (score 0):

MQL4 and MQL5 are different in terms of indicators. You can use indicator directly where you need it, but that is usually not convenient and requires different code for MQL4 and MQL5.

You can create an instance of an indicator (of course different parameters means different instances). Different indicators may have different number of parameters and buffers, so it makes sense to create a class for each indicator you need. This approach is both good for MQL4 and MQL5.

```
#include <Indicators\Custom.mqh>
class CiMyCustomIndicator : public CiCustom
   {
       string  m_indicatorName;
    public:
       int     GetResult(const int index)const//as an example, buf0[0]>buf0[1] -> 1, buf0[0]<buf0[1] -> -1, else 0
          {
           double value=GetData(0,index),
                  prevValue=GetData(0,index+1);
           if(value>prevValue)return(1);
           if(value<prevValue)return(-1);
           return(0);
          }
   };

 int OnInit(){
    CiMyCustomIndicator *myMacd=new CiMyCustomIndicator();
    //lets assume myMacd gets two params:int InpPeriod=9; double InpLine=0.0001;
    MqlParams[] myMacdInputs;
    ArrayResize(myMacdInputs,2);
    myMacdInputs[0].type=TYPE_INT;
    myMacd[0].integer_value=InpPeriod;
    myMacdInputs[1].type=TYPE_DOUBLE;
    myMacdInputs[1].double_value=InpLine;

    myMacd.Create(_Symbol,_Period,IND_CUSTOM,ArraySize(myMacdInputs),myMacdInputs);
// you can now pass myMacd as pointer into another method
// other logic

}
void OnDeinit(const int reason){delete(myMacd);}
void OnTick(){
     double value=myMacd.GetData(bufferIndex, shift);
     int customResult=myMacd.GetResult(shift);
}
```

Comment: I agree with your code, but I don't think it makes sense to pass a generic indicator since all indicators output different values. It would make more sense to create a Abstract Base Class for a generic signal with a `virtual SIGNAL method()` and then subclass it with indicator and logic to return the appropriate signal. ...kinda like how the MQL5 wizards does.

Comment: not sure I understand how indicator and signal are related. indicator can be a filter, or it can be used to compute sl/tp/trail etc

Comment: Thanks, i already made a class for each indicator, which is tedious as i took like a day to make classes for 10 indicators, also i ended up adding customization to each class, and inheritance and interfaces are not as powerful as C#

Comment: yes, `Ramzy` they are not so good but at least exist :) Reflection is not available at all :((, as well as error handling/catching or multithreading

Comment: Yeah, I have to minimize my use of MQL5 to Indicators and Market Orders, any i make a RESTful webservice in Flask to handle any computation including Prediction. but i still have to suffer in MQL5 xD